# AWS CodeBuild Github webhook does not update status of PullRequest

Tags: github, githooks, aws-codebuild

Using the official guide, created build project to run tests on GitHub PullRequests creation. The webhook is correctly shown on GitHub, builds are being triggered in Codebuild, however, the build status is not shown in Github, despite the option Report build status is set **true**. If I correctly understood the tutorial, Codebuild has native support of GitHub, and after successful creation of a webhook, the new verification check should be added for PR submission automatically, any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

Ensure the GitHub user has **write** access to the repository, and if you're using a Personal Access Token (PAT), ensure the `repo:status` scope is granted:

> Grants read/write access to public and private repository commit statuses. This scope is only necessary to grant other users or services access to private repository commit statuses without granting access to the code.

https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/

(I experienced this issue recently. The PAT had the necessary scopes granted but the GitHub user had **read-only** access to the repository. Granting the GitHub user write permission solved the problem.)

Answer (score 4):

It should work automatically. If builds are triggering but codebuild is not reporting back on the status, then it sounds like the codebuild project no longer has permission to the repo. You could try adding the GitHub source to codebuild again.

"Report build status" actually has no effect when triggered by a webhook, and should always report back in theory (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/change-project.html). It's set to false for my project and always updates the pull requests.

Comment: Hi,  

Thanks for suggestions, I already tried re-adding the source, creating the project from scratch, and revoking Codebuild access to Github, but no luck with that.  

Codebuild has all permissions to Github account:  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyruomt8ghkjtve/Screenshot%202018-09-15%2017.29.52.png?dl=0  

Also, it is approved by Third-party application access policy in my org settings.  

Here is what I see in PR:  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyruomt8ghkjtve/Screenshot%202018-09-15%2017.29.52.png?dl=0

Comment: @RomanKolodiy were you ever able to figure out why Codebuild is not reporting status back to GitHub? I'm having this problem as well on a pull request that I ran a job manually for.

Comment: @dimiguel, check your permissions in the organization and repo, enabling administrator rights for org solved an issue in my case.

Comment: What do you mean "Report build status actually has no effect when triggered by a webhook" - when is it triggered? Is it possible to turn it off for a webhook e.g. for testing?